# How to iterate in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python but I have gone thru the syntax. Here's my scenario:

I have two instances of Cursors `AllImages` & `AllAlbums` (I'm getting the data from a db & I'm getting them like this:

```
AllImages = Images.find()
AllAlbums = Albums.find()
```

)

**[Edit: I'm using the PyMongo API]**

Inside every dictionary in `AllAlbums` I have an array of numbers called `images = [1234,2234,16363]`

Inside every dictionary in `All Images` I have a field called `_id`

Here's how both dicts look like:

From `AllAlbums`:

```
{ _id:23
  images:[1123,6643,4,9087]
}
```

From `AllImages`:

```
{ _id:6643}
```

Now, I need to see if this `_id` is present in `images`

This is what I've written so far:

```
for img in AllImages:
    for alAl in AllAlbums:
        alIm = alAl['images']
        for qq in alIm:
            if qq==img['_id']:
                print 'Here!',img['_id'],' with',alAl['_id']
```

Now here's what I get for output:

The program correctly matches `_id` = `0` in `images` for a dictionary in  `AllAlbums` with `_id` of 69.

However, after that (for the rest of the `_id`s like 1,2,3...8899...9999) it does not enter into the second `for` loop to iterate. Yes, I know my approach is probably crude and all, but I just need this basic code to run.

How do I re-iterate this cursor for `AllAlbums` ?

Apologies if I've not formatted the code properly. I'm on Python 2.7

Comment: How are AllImages and AllAlbums created ? Can you `print list(AllImages)` and and `print list(AllAlbums)` and show us the output ? Or at least part of it ?

Comment: The only conditional is inside the third loop, so it should always enter the second loop, unless AllAlbums is empty. There are obvious problems with the code, but it should work; I don't see what would cause the behaviour you describe. Could you give us a real example of inputs and outputs, if you can demonstrate the problem with a small collection?

Comment: I know, right! Well, I have provided with real examples of results. However, I'll post another one:

`{_id:6809}` and `{_id:29, images:[6809,2234,6709,9985]}`

I know it should print `'Here!'` for this condition as well BUT it does NOT do the iteration after it's done with `_id:0`

Comment: @ddelemeny - Hi! I realized my mistake - `AllImages` & `AllAlbums` are instances of Cursor (since I obtained them from the Database) - which is probably the reason this is happening! How would I re-iterate over a cursor?

Comment: @Saturnian the usual way is to turn them into lists, which do support multiple iterations - if your initial assignment of `AllImages` looks like `AllImages = some_magic()`, change it to `AllImages = list(some_magic())`.

Comment: @Saturnian :) Problems happening in a snippet are usually caused outside of the snippet. It's good to always try to provide as much detail on the context of your problem as possible, a minimal working example being top level info. As for the cursor : store the result as a list in a variable and iterate on the list.

Comment: @ddelemeny I thought I was probably receiving a list! A quick Google search later I realized it wasn't so. So I did `AllAlbumsList = list(AllAbums)` and it worked! Thanks a million! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple.

I simply made a list out of the cursor instance `AllAlbums` and was able to re-iterate multiple times. Thanks a lot to those who pointed this out to me (:

`AllAlbumList = list(AllAlbums)`

Comment: you don't need a list, you could use `for img, alAl itertools.product(AllImages, AllAlbums):`

Comment: I could try this out. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

A definition of a dictionary from AllAlbums should be something like this:

```
album = {'_id': 23, 'images': [1123, 6643, 4, 9087]}
```

(It could have more fields, of course.)

Assuming that `AllImages` and `AllAlbums` are lists, you could use a list comprehension.

```
with_image = [a for a in AllAlbums if 6643 in a[`images`]]
```

Comment: I think I realised my mistake. `AllAlbums` & `AllImages` are instances of `Cursor` ! So obviously when it's done cruising over all dicts for the first iteration of `AllImages` I believe it won't set itself back to point to the beginning.

By any chance would you know how to re-iterate over a cursor?

Comment: @Saturnian: which database are we talking about here? There are several that have Python interfaces...

Comment: MongoDB; using the PyMongo API. I resolved the issue by making a list of the cursor - `AllAlbumsList = list(AllAlbums)`

That worked for me, thanks so much! (:

Comment: I feel like there must he a query syntax that will do this for you in a non **O(n^2)** way...